# How to find out if a type implements generics base class

Tags: c#, generics

Using the example below... how can I find out whether a property is of a type implementing generics class Foo?

```
public class Foo<TBaz>
{

}

public class Bar
{
    public Foo<int> FooInt { get; set; }
    public Foo<string> FooString { get; set; }
    public double SomeOther { get; set; }

    public int GetFooCount()
    {
        return typeof(Bar).GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetType().IsGenericType).Count();
    }
}
```

If I wanted to find `Foo<int>`, it would be easy, but how can I find out if it contains `Foo<int>`, `Foo<double>` etc...?

I have written the bit of GetFooCount() I have so far...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return typeof(Bar).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
    && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Foo<>)).Count();
```

Note: this won't automatically work for `class NonGenericSubtype : Foo<Blah> {...}`, nor will it work for `class GenericSubtype<T> : Foo<T> {...}` - if you need to handle those, it gets more fun.

For the more general case, you would need something that uses recursion on the type:

```
public static int GetFooCount()
{
    return typeof(Bar).GetProperties()
        .Count(p => GetFooType(p.PropertyType) != null);
}

private static Type GetFooType(Type type)
{
    while(type != null)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType &&
            type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Foo<>))
                return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note this also answers "now how do I find `T`?"

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Will mark as answer in 12 minutes!